# NullPointerException when using JavaFX

Tags: java, svg, nullpointerexception, javafx-2, fxml

I am facing a NullPointerException and I can't figure out where or why it occurs. I'm using JavaFX for a project, and it contains a .fxml file which has lots of components (mostly SVGPaths, Circle objects and Text objects). They are imported into a Controller class. Each SVGPath has a mouse listener (for click, enter and exit actions) and sometimes I get a NullPointerException that makes me crazy because I have spent hours trying to solve it. Here is the exact stack trace of exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper.computeBoundsLogical(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper.computeContentBounds(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$2.computeBounds(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$ContentView.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.layoutDirtyRoots(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3900(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I will appreciate it a lot if someone can help and also explain the reason of this occurrence.

Comment: This has all the appearances of being a bug in JavaFX. I am looking for a reference, but don't have access to the best places to look...

Comment: You are not the first person to see this one: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2540126

Comment: yeap i saw that post this morning and i opened a thread there also,however, nobody has answered yet. Maybe this is a bug of JavaFX as you said, but this issue is becoming quite annoying for me :). On the other hand, thanks for your response.

Comment: Try [Java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and see if you still have an issue.  If you do, then you can debug the issue against the [JavaFX source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt) or log the issue in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: i realized that i use `JavaFX 2.0 SDK` and `JavaFX 2.2 Runtime` (both of them are 64-bit). Will this difference between versions cause to `NullPointerException` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you already solved this, but maybe my solution will help others.

If you are working with JavaFX in a Swing Application you have to be careful to only execute JavaFX code in the correspondent thread and to run Swing code only in the EDT.

I was having a similar problem in my application and it was due to the execution of JavaFX code in the EDT. So, to correct this, I reviewed the code to ensure the use of Platform.runLater(...) on methods that were possibly called from the EDT.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // JavaFX manipulation code.
  }
}
```

This seems easy but can be tricky to remember sometimes. So, to be sure, review your JavaFX code searching for public methods and interfaces that can be invoked by Swing components and events.